# Execute method in Rails 4.1.1 migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to run migration for this file:

```
class AddIndexToUsernameDowncaseForUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'CREATE INDEX index_users_on_username_downcase ON users (lower(username));'
  end

  def down
    remove_index :users, name: :index_users_on_username_downcase
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
== 20140521043803 AddIndexToUsernameDowncaseForUsers: migrating ===============
--     execute("CREATE INDEX index_users_on_username_downcase ON groups lower(username);")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `    execute' for #<AddIndexToUsernameDowncaseForUsers:0x007fea8a9b9c50>/Users/mydir/db/migrate/20140521043803_add_index_to_username_downcase_for_users.rb:3:in `up'
NoMethodError: undefined method `    execute' for #<AddIndexToUsernameDowncaseForUsers:0x007fea8a9b9c50>
/Users/mydir/db/migrate/20140521043803_add_index_to_username_downcase_for_users.rb:3:in `up'
```

I'm really confused as I've  never had issues running migrations before. It looks like the helpers aren't getting included or something. Pretty stumped, but my guess is this is a facepalm-level issue by me.

Rails 4.1.1, Ruby 2.1.1, Postgres 9.3

Comment: Do you have any unprintable/control characters at the start of the `execute` line?  There seems to be 4 characters before `execute` when it runs and within the quotes in the error: `'    execute'`

Comment: Thanks Graeme. That did it for me. Not sure how they got in there, either, esp since I'm using VIM which usually shows weird chars. Feel free to submit as an answer so you can get your well-deserved points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 unprintable characters before the word `execute` - it shows both when it echoes the statement during the migration and also within the quotes in the error: `'    execute'`.

So it's actually looking for a method called `....execute` where `....` are those characters.